# How to test stubs in failing code?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, stub

I have a piece of code that retries a certain API call 3 times before failing. I also have a stub for this API.

I want to write two tests in the case of failure:

- The whole thing fails;
- The API has been called three times.

Here is the first test:

```
it 'fails' do
  expect { risky_call } to raise_error SomeError
end
```

The second test however, is a bit trickier:

```
it 'calls the API three times' do
  risky_call
  expect(stub).to have_been_requested.times(3)
end
```

The problem is that `risky_call` raises `SomeError`, making the test fail. I thought of doing something like this:

```
it 'calls the API three times' do
  risky_call rescue nil
  expect(stub).to have_been_requested.times(3)
end
```

But it does seem very hackish.

Is there a better/safer/more idiomatic way to write this spec?

Comment: Try to put `risky_call` after the `expect` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, the expect fails since no calls have been made when the expectation gets evaluated. `The request was expected to execute 3 times but it executed 0 times.`

Comment: May be the exception was raised before any of the API calls.

Comment: Does your "very hackish" test actually pass?

Comment: Yes, it passes. Is there nothing better than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your stub looks like but this appears to be one of those times where the single expectation per test rule need not apply.

Your specification is very clear it should try 3 times before raising an error so a test like

```
it 'calls the API three times before raising an error' do
  expect { risky_call }.to raise_error(SomeError)
  expect(stub).to have_been_requested.times(3)
end
```

Makes logical sense to me. Expecting it to "call 3 times" without context does not. What if it only calls 1 time or 2 times? This makes your test description misleading. The new description explains that it will retry 3 times before an error is raised which is what you actually meant and is easy to understand.

Comment: I've thought of aggregating the specs, I guess it makes sense. Also, when writing this kind of spec, I find that [`:aggregate_failures`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures) help maintain the atomic spirit of unit tests. Cheers!

Comment: @Richard-Degenne yes I am certainly aware of method (although I use it quite infrequently) more to the point was that making sure it raises an error as 1 test does not necessarily guarantee 3 requests and checking that there were 3 requests in another test does necessarily guarantee an error was raised. Combining them into a single test ensures that 3 calls were made before the error and that the error is only raised after 3 calls and *"...5 is right out"*